# How to add sequential numbers next to data from query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table named `tblFriends`:

[image]

`tblFriends` is generated from query `qryFriends`. The data and number of records within `tblFriends` changes everyday but is never more than 30.

I would like to generate sequential numbers next to each of the Names, but this seems to be extremely difficult.

I have tried looping insert queries as shown below:

```
strSQLaddSEQ = "ALTER TABLE tblFriends ADD SEQ Number;"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLaddSEQ

For SEQNum = 1 To 30

   strSqlSEQNum = "INSERT INTO Friends (SEQ) Values(" & SEQNum & ");"
   DoCmd.RunSQL strSqlSEQNum

Next SEQNum
```

This always results in my SEQ numbers showing up below the data even though it's a newly created field.

How do I simply add sequence numbers from 1-30 next to my data? Or at the very least how do I add a sequence number for the data I have?

(Maybe?)Is there a way to maybe loop through each row(row by row) copying to a new table then creating a SEQ number there and repeating 30 times? I don't care even if I need to do this field by field row by row.

For example, I'm ok if I need to simply go:

```
1 - Bikes
2 - Food
3 - Money
4 - Shoes
5 - Computers 
6 - Clothes
7 - Soda
```

But how do I go row by row like that and maintain sequence order I had from the start? Is there a looping process?

The initial record sequence is important and needs to be maintained.

Comment: True, not simple in Access query but it is simple in Access report where textbox has RunningSum property. If you want to save into table, that would require an UPDATE action SQL (not INSERT) or as you indicated, writing records to another table. If you need to maintain original record order, then need to enter a sequence value at time record is created. Why not use an autonumber field? Why do number of records in table fluctuate up and down?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the solution to my own question...but I haven't tested it yet since I'm home now and don't have my work computer.

Assume I've created a table named tblSeqNames with fields "Names” and "SEQ".

```
Dim rs As Recordset

Dim strNames As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryFriends", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblSeqNames (Names, SEQ) VALUES ('" & strNames & "', " & SEQNum & ")"

For SEQNum = 1 To 30

    strNames = rs.Fields("Name").Value

        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

    rs.MoveNext

Next SEQNum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an external function which you pass the form as an argument.

It's very simple to implement. Study the in-line comments:

```vb
' Creates and returns a sequential record number for records displayed
' in a form, even if no primary or unique key is present.
' For a new record, Null is returned until the record is saved.
'
' Implementation, typical:
'
'   Create a TextBox to display the record number.
'   Set the ControlSource of this to:
'
'       =RecordNumber([Form])
'
'   The returned number will equal the Current Record displayed in the
'   form's record navigator (bottom-left).
'   Optionally, specify another first number than 1, say, 0:
'
'       =RecordNumber([Form],0)
'
'   NB: For localised versions of Access, when entering the expression, type
'
'       =RecordNumber([LocalisedNameOfObjectForm])
'
'   for example:
'
'       =RecordNumber([Formular])
'
'   and press Enter. The expression will update to:
'
'       =RecordNumber([Form])
'
'   If the form can delete records, insert this code line in the
'   AfterDelConfirm event:
'
'       Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
'           Me!RecordNumber.Requery
'       End Sub
'
'   If the form can add records, insert this code line in the
'   AfterInsert event:
'
'       Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
'           Me!RecordNumber.Requery
'       End Sub
'
' Implementation, stand-alone:
'
'   Dim Number As Variant
'
'   Number = RecordNumber(Forms(IndexOfFormInFormsCollection))
'   ' or
'   Number = RecordNumber(Forms("NameOfSomeOpenForm"))
'
'
' 2018-09-14. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RecordNumber( _
    ByRef Form As Access.Form, _
    Optional ByVal FirstNumber As Long = 1) _
    As Variant

    ' Error code for "There is no current record."
    Const NoCurrentRecord   As Long = 3021
    
    Dim Records             As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim Number              As Variant
    Dim Prompt              As String
    Dim Buttons             As VbMsgBoxStyle
    Dim Title               As String

    On Error GoTo Err_RecordNumber
    If Form Is Nothing Then
        ' No form object is passed.
        Number = Null
    ElseIf Form.Dirty = True Then
        ' No record number until the record is saved.
        Number = Null
    ElseIf Form.NewRecord = True Then
        ' No record number on a new record.
        Number = Null
    Else
        Set Records = Form.RecordsetClone
        Records.Bookmark = Form.Bookmark
        Number = FirstNumber + Records.AbsolutePosition
        Set Records = Nothing
    End If
    
Exit_RecordNumber:
    RecordNumber = Number
    Exit Function
    
Err_RecordNumber:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case NoCurrentRecord
            ' Form is at new record, thus no Bookmark exists.
            ' Ignore and continue.
        Case Else
            ' Unexpected error.
            Prompt = "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
            Buttons = vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            Title = Form.Name
            MsgBox Prompt, Buttons, Title
    End Select
    
    ' Return Null for any error.
    Number = Null
    Resume Exit_RecordNumber

End Function
```

It is part of my project [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers) where you will find a lot of other methods to enumerate rows, each with some advanteges and disadvantages.